# how to properly layout main contents with Material-Ui-Next Mini variant Drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-v4

I am trying to build my layout using `material-ui-next`'s Mini variant Drawer. I want my components - Home, Login, Register etc to be rendered inside Drawer's `<main className={classes.content}>`. What is the right way? Should I import Home, Login, Register and Router in Drawer component? or Is there a better way?

related images :

[image: picture-1]

[image: picture-2]

[image: picture-3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Component` we pass into `react-router`'s `Route` component gets rendered on match. A `<Switch>` renders the first child `<Route>` that matches. So there are two ways you can render these components under `<main>` of MiniDrawer :

1- write your `<Switch><Route>...</Switch>` as children of MiniDrawer in your `App.js`, like

```
<MiniDrawer>
    <Switch>
      <Route>...
       ...
    </Switch>
</MiniDrawer>
```

and

in `MiniDrawer.js` :

```
<main className={classes.content}>
    {this.props.children}
 </main>
```

2- **or** you can write your 
`<Switch><Route>...</Switch>` inside `<main>` in MiniDrawer